# To add a list of Strings to Lucene document

Tags: string, list, lucene

Suppose I've a field which is a List (Say : "Key" : ["value1", "value2", "value3"]. How do add it to a lucene document in a sequence map. I'm currently loading the content from a file in a sequence and mapping each entry to a document and for each entry adding the document using index writer.

```
seq(items)
        .map(item -> {
            Document document = new Document();
            document.add(new TextField("field", item.field(), Field.Store.YES));
            return document;
        })
        .forEach(consumer(indexWriter::addDocument));
```

I'm not struggling to add a field which is a list of strings to the above index document. Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a document per value in that field but conversely, using the same document you just use `document.add(<field>)` for each value of the list (provided that *field* is defined as multivalued) :

```
Document document = new Document();
seq(items).map(item -> {
  document.add(new TextField('field', item.field(), Field.Store.YES));
});
yourIndexWriter.addDocument(document);
```

Comment: Hi EricLavault, Thankyou for the response. the question was more around how to add a field that is a list of strings to the document. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: Well.. this is exactly what the code above is doing. It creates one document to be indexed, then for each value of the given string list, add it to the document's *'field'* (ie. single field with multiple values) and then send the doc to solr.

Comment: Oh ! my bad, sorry ! Thankyou for the response.